# Encrypting and Decrypting a 19-digits long BigInteger

Tags: c#, encryption, cryptography, biginteger

How can I take a maximum 19-digits long `BigInteger` and encrypt it with the following rules:

- The result must be based on digits and lower-case English letters only.
- All outputs must have the same length to any input. The length must be between 11 to 16 characters, depending on your method, *but should be consistent for all possible inputs*.
- No easy patterns. For example, if you encrypt 000...1 and 000...2 the results should look completely different.
- No collisions at all
- Should be able to decrypt back to the original BigInteger.

**Things that I have tried**

- Take the original number, XOR it by some key, multiply it by a factor and convert it to a base 36 string. The purpose of the factor is to expand the range so there won't be too much 0 padding. The factor must be between 1 to `36^16/10^19`. The problem with this method is that a) it's not 'secure' enough, and b) close numbers have very similar results.
- [This answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2565861/140937) However, the result was often too short or too long, and the factor method used before didn't work here.

Comment: That looks very much like a homework assignment. Is it?

Comment: How is it a homework assignment? The complexity of this problem is much harder than most homework tasks.

Comment: Can the BigInteger be negative? How will you manage the key?

Comment: I said that it looks like homework, mostly the elaborate specification for a limited task.

Comment: I would suggest posting this to http://crypto.stackexchange.com instead of SO.

Comment: [Consider this](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/sci.crypt/bK8mSWeC41k) for something simple.

Comment: No, the BigInteger can't be negative.

Comment: @Alon, then you can simply encode it to bytes, making sure that you left pad with zero's if required, and if it gets over 8 bytes, that you remove the zero valued byte at the left.

Comment: @Guffa and if this *isn't* homework, I *shudder* to think what it's for.

Comment: Cross posted on [crypto.SE](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/6765/encrypting-and-decrypting-a-19-digits-long-biginteger). Please don't cross-post, especially without linking to the other question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

19 digits is slightly less than 64 bits, so you can simply use a 8 byte block cipher like TDEA in ECB mode to encrypt the BigInteger values. First retrieve a default 64 bit encoding of the BigInteger, then encrypt with the secret key, and finally base 36 encode it. The result will be a few characters less than 16 characters, but you can always pad with any value.

Note that if you encrypt the same value twice that you will get the same result, so in that respect the ciphertext does leak some information about the plain text.

Comment: I implemented this using the BigInteger and TripleDES classes in C#. The problem I've encountred is that numbers close to 9999999999999999999 are too large for one block. Also, length of most numbers go between 12-13 digits, I need them all to be have a fixed length. Padding a 0 is not an option here because most results would start with a 0.

Comment: @Alon: 9999999999999999999 should fit in an unsigned 64 bit variable. It won't fit in a signed one, though.

Comment: @IlmariKaronen yeah, seems like I **was** paying attention, 19 zero's with a one before that should fit. I was just wrong footed when it when Alon said it didn't fit.

Comment: Alon, padding is fine both before and after encryption. As long as the value stays unique (and it will) then you can simply pad with leading zero bytes. If you pad after encryption then you will of course see bytes with special values, but that won't say anything about the plain text.

Comment: This can't work. The requirement is that the encryption function is length perserving  and only outputs a-z and 0-9. Encryption functions output over a larger range. Because of the length perserving requirement, you can't encode those bytes into a-z 0-9 either with out increasing the length.

Comment: @imichaelmiers: The requirement is to preserve the length of an input which is originally *just in digits*. That gives a lot more space to play with - the binary output can be twice the size of the binary input, and and we can still preserve the original *text* length.

Comment: Exactly, the output can simply be base36 encoded and, if required, padded to the same length, without breaking any of the requirements.

Comment: Thank you kindly, that took my total over 10K reputation, giving me access to moderator tools.

Answer (score 0):

The technique you want is [format perserving encryption](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Format-preserving_encryption).  This will allow you to encrypt a 19 digit number as another 19 digit number.

Unfortunately, the efficient version of this technique is somewhat difficult to implement and in fact can be done very insecurely  if you pick the wrong paramaters. There are libraries for it. 
[This one](http://botan.randombit.net/fpe.html) is open source. It is in C++ unfortunately  and its not clear if it runs on windows.  [Voltage](https://www.voltage.com/technology/format-preserving-encryption/) has a library as well, though it presumably costs money and I'm not sure what languages  they support.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a piece of code that seems to do it, provided you can convert the `BigInteger` into an `ulong` (9999999999999999999 is in fact an `ulong`). The result is always a fixed 16 characters string (hexadecimal).

```
    byte[] key = // put your 16-bytes private key here
    byte[] iv = Guid.NewGuid().ToByteArray(); // or anything that varies and you can carry

    string s = EncryptUInt64(ul, key, iv); // encode
    ulong dul = DecryptUInt64(s, key, iv).Value; // decode if possible


    public static string EncryptUInt64(ulong ul, byte[] key, byte[] iv)
    {
        using (MemoryStream output = new MemoryStream())
        using (var algo = TripleDES.Create())
        {
            algo.Padding = PaddingMode.None;
            using (CryptoStream stream = new CryptoStream(output, algo.CreateEncryptor(key, iv), CryptoStreamMode.Write))
            {
                byte[] ulb = BitConverter.GetBytes(ul);
                stream.Write(ulb, 0, ulb.Length);
            }
            return BitConverter.ToUInt64(output.ToArray(), 0).ToString("x16");
        }
    }

    public static ulong? DecryptUInt64(string text, byte[] key, byte[] iv)
    {
        if (text == null)
            return null;

        ulong ul;
        if (!ulong.TryParse(text, NumberStyles.HexNumber, null, out ul))
            return null;

        using (MemoryStream input = new MemoryStream(BitConverter.GetBytes(ul)))
        using (var algo = TripleDES.Create())
        {
            algo.Padding = PaddingMode.None;
            using (CryptoStream stream = new CryptoStream(input, algo.CreateDecryptor(key, iv), CryptoStreamMode.Read))
            {
                byte[] olb = new byte[8];
                try
                {
                    stream.Read(olb, 0, olb.Length);
                }
                catch
                {
                    return null;
                }
                return BitConverter.ToUInt64(olb, 0);
            }
        }
    }
```