# How to create unpredictable userids?

Tags: php, mysql, facebook, algorithm

I want users on my site to be able to change their username anytime and they can login with email or password.

Still under the hood I have to define ids because of the similar requirements in the Facebook. Facebook assigns users a unique number when they register and it uses that number in numerous ways.

We at least need something that won't change and not created by user; so, when necessary, user can be identified by that number.

Facebook does not increment these numbers by 1. Like an auto-increment int value in the database. This is good, because you can't estimate number of users instantly and you can't surf through the system by just incrementing userids one by one.

What is the best way to handle this situation and how does Facebook do this?

Is there a common algorithm or technic to do this?

Comment: I was under the impression Facebook user IDs were numeric? But the IDs aren’t just for users, as users—like pages and so on—are just Graph objects.

Comment: Is there a reason your user IDs *shouldn’t* be auto-incremented? As in, does it pose a security risk? As otherwise you’re just making life complicated for yourself.

Comment: Why is an unpredictable user id so critical?

Comment: Because of the same reason that Facebook does. less susceptible to `for(i++)fetch_profile(i);` etc.. and better at hiding number of total users. Facebook uses this everwhere internally (but visible) like https://www.facebook.com/profile.php?id=749315278&viewer_id=766123409

Comment: GUID? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Globally_unique_identifier

Comment: Possibly set up a table of unique values in advance, and select a random value from it, deleting it / flagging it at the same time as you assign it. When many are used then just add some more unique values.

Comment: StackOverflow is happy with auto-incremented IDs. Just because one site does it one way doesn't mean it makes sense for another site to do it the same way.

Answer (score 2):

You should generate your ids as auto-incremented numbers. You can then apply a reversible transformation to that number so that it *looks* like it was randomly generated. The accepted answer to [Integer ID obfuscation techniques](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2565478/56778) gives a good example using [Pearson hashing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pearson_hashing).

The result of that might be an uncomfortably large number to type. For example, user id 13 might get converted to 4795368201. If that's a problem for your users, you could encode the result using base64 or something similar.

Answer (score 1):

Well that's quite simple use php rand() with num values only, and make a loop checking if the database contains the generated ID, if it's true then thanks to a loop it generates a new ID and so on, if it's false register your user using this ID.

Facebook is using a unique ID for every item on their website, it means that a user can have an ID but if you take that ID and you add +1 you'll maybe get a photo, or a post...