# How to generate a pin code in Symfony

Tags: security, symfony

I'm working right now on a symfony2 web app and I need to generate automatically and randomly pin-code composed by 6 alphanumeric characters example:

> 14gkf8
>   kfgh88

this code will be sent by mail to the use, that's how he will connect to the platform.
anyone have an idea how to make it or there is maybe a ready tool to do it ? thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can generate random codes with the following code:

```
substr(bin2hex(openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(100)), 0, 6)
```

[Online demo](http://missingbrackets.com/codepad/editor/6MnEII).

[`openssl_random_pseudo_bytes()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.openssl-random-pseudo-bytes.php) will generate random binary data, [`bin2hex()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.openssl-random-pseudo-bytes.php) will transform this binary data as hexadecimal data (e.g. `5c3aa…e55`) and [substr(…, 0, 6)](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php) will keep only the 6 first characters. Since hexadecimal uses values from `0` to `9` and `a` to `f`, there is 16 different characters available at each position, so it gives `16^6 = 16,777,216` possibilities (with `0` to `9` and `a` to `z` it's `36^6 = 2,176,782,336`, only ± 130 times more). If the user doesn't need to type the key, you can use more characters, for example with 12 characters you have many more possibilities: `16^12 = 2,814×10¹⁴`.

Comment: thanks @A.L .. i'll start by 6 characters to make it easier for the users, than maybe one day i'll add some characters

Answer (score 2):

You can use `uniqid()` to generate a unique alphanumeric string

Comment: It seems dangerous since the result is predictable (as noted in the [PHP documentation](http://php.net/manual/function.uniqid.php)) and the OP wants a code in order to identify the users. Examples by calling this code after several seconds: `5548f22923c9f`, `5548f229b1852`, … That's not random.

Comment: Good catch A.L in this case I think he should do somme crypto functions like you have posted or like this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2565478/integer-id-obfuscation-techniques