# How can I encode an id in url in ActionResult in asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I need to encode the id before returning view. The id can be easily guessed when passed in url so I am trying to encode before returning in View

```
     [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Index(int id = 0)
    {
        var model = new ReviewModel();
        if (id != 0)
        {
            model.Id = id;
            model = model.Get();
             //How can I encode model.Id here***
        }
        ViewBag.IsAdmin = model.IsAdmin(User.Identity.Name);
        model.SaveAudit("Visits Code of Conduct", User.Identity.Name);



        return View(model);
    }
```

Comment: Simply don't use numeric constantly growing IDs, but rather hashes to identify your model entities. You would need to store those hashes together with other model properties.

Comment: BTW your `Index` action is irrelevant, it will stay the same except of changing `int id` to `string hash` or something like that. Important part is where your model entities are created and persisted. On such place you have to create the entity's hash. The rest stays the same.

Comment: This question would be no different without the code you posted. You're basically asking people to do your homework.

Answer (score 0):

**Consider Non-Integer Identifiers or Manual Encryption/Decryption**

Since it's an integer, your options as far as attempting to encode it are going to be fairly limited if you want to consider storing it on your model still. If you have the ability to store some type of more unique identifier such as `Guid`, then that might be preferable as it would take out the element of a user attempting to "guess" or alter the value.

I suppose you could create some type of hash based on your integer value and pass that along (you would need update your value accordingly) and then decrypt the hashed value on the `POST` side of the request [similar to the approach mentioned in this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2565861/557445).

**Possibly Temporary Storage Usage**

One consideration could be to use some form of temporary storage like `TempData` to store the value so that it would be available on the subsequent request :

```
if (id != 0)
{
        model.Id = id;
        model = model.Get();
        // Store the ID in TempData
        TempData["CurrentReviewID"] = id;
}
```

And then when your following request, presumably the `POST` that cooresponds to this is triggered, you could read your value from the `TempData` collection and use it :

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(ReviewModel model)
{
      // Resolve your ID here
      int int = Convert.ToInt32(TempData["CurrentReviewID"]);

      // Continue as expected
}
```

Approaches like this or *gulp* the `Session` could be used to persist this kind of information between requests, but this can add an element of statefulness to your applications, which you generally want to avoid in MVC applications.